# Uncaught TypeError: n is not a constructor with Bootstrap 4 dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-4, dropdown, popper.js

I have multiple dropdown menus in my page. Located inside the nav works fine, but the inside of the page does not work

**Located inside the nav**

[image]

**inside of the page**

[image]

[image]

what is the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bootstrap is not yet compatible with Popper.js version 2, see https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2385#issuecomment-579892665.

The bundle works because it bundles the right version of Popper, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/.

Answer (score 3):

bootstrap.bundle.min.js or bootstrap.bundle.js solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As it answer before... popper js v2 not compatible with boostrap

you need to downgrade the popper.js version

cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```